# Select highest value over multiple tables

Tags: sql

I have the following tables

```
Table Name : tHREmployee

EmployeID#      Employee    DepartmentID    DesignationID     DOB           BasicPay
101             Ajith       101             102              10/Feb/1982    10000
102             Aarathy     NULL            101              15/Mar/1981    15000
103             Aruna       102             NULL             20/Sep/1980    5000
104             Ambily      101             NULL             20/Sep/1980    5000
105             Anjaly      NULL            101              20/Sep/1980    10000
106             Babitha     103             NULL             20/Sep/1981    20000 



Table Name : tHRDepartment
DepartmentID#   Code    Department
101             500     Production
102             501     HR
103             502     Finance
105             503     Marketing


Table Name : tHRDesignation

DesignationID#  Designation

101             Executive
102             Manager
```

How can I display employee details (Employee, Department, Designation, basicPay) for those employees who have highest basic pay for each department in sql?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far and explain why that didn't work?

Comment: Which DB is this?? ORACLE?

Comment: Select  a.Employee, c.Designation, b.Department,  a.BasicPay from tHREmployee
 left join tHRDepartment b on a.DepartmentID= b.DepartmentID
left  join tHRDesignation  c on a.DesignationID=c. DesignationID                           
where  a.BasicPay in (select max(BasicPay) from tHREmployee group by b.DepartmentID)

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, this should help you

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
  SELECT DepartmentID    , MAX(BasicPay) MAXPAY FROM tHREmployee 
  GROUP BY DepartmentID    
)
SELECT E.EmployeID EMPid, E.Employee  EMP_NAME , DPT.Department DPT_NAME, 
DSG.Designation DSG_NAME, BASICPAY

FROM CTE, tHREmployee E,tHRDepartment DPT, Designation DSG
WHERE 
E.BASICPAY = MAXPAY 
AND E.DepartmentID  = CTE.DepartmentID    
AND E.DepartmentID  = DPT.DepartmentID    
AND E.DesignationID = DSG.DesignationID
```

In other DBs, something similar to this would help you:

```
SELECT E.EmployeID EMPid, E.Employee  EMP_NAME , DPT.Department DPT_NAME, 
DSG.Designation DSG_NAME, BASICPAY
FROM tHREmployee E,tHRDepartment DPT, Designation DSG
WHERE 
E.DepartmentID  = CTE.DepartmentID    
AND E.DepartmentID  = DPT.DepartmentID    
AND E.DesignationID = DSG.DesignationID   
AND E.BASICPAY IN 
( SELECT MAX(EE.BASICPAY) FROM tHREmployee EE GROUP BY DPT.DepartmentID   )
```

Answer (score 0):

Select    A.Employee,B.Department ,c.Designation,a.BAsicPay    from    Employee    A    inner    join    Department    B    on    A.Department=B.DepartmentID    left    join    Designation    C    on    A.designationID=C.DesignationID    inner    join     (Select DepartmentID,max(BasicPay)    as    BasicPay    from    Employee    group    by     DepartmentID)    as    s2
on    s2.DepartmentID=A.DepartmentID    and    A.BAsicPay=s2.BasicPAy